# highcharts jquery dynamic change chart type column to bar

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to switch of graph type using jquery.

I found the way to change dinamically the chart type (without recreating a new chart) by using the function :

series[i].update({ type: chartType});

My first question will be : There is a way to change the all chart and not just the series ? If not keep reading :)

But with this function i'm not able to make the 'bar' chart working. It's acting like a column chart. As you can see the pie example is working as excepted.

bar : http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic

How it works(sample example) :

```html
<div id="top10_" style="float:left">
    <button id="set_column">column</button>
    <button id="set_bar">bar</button>
    <button id="set_pie">pie</button>
</div>
<div id="top10" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
```

```js
$('#set_column').click(function () {
    var chart = $(this).parent('div').attr('id');
    chart = chart.replace('_', '');
    $('#' + chart).highcharts().series[0].update({
        type: "column"
    });
});
$('#set_bar').click(function () {
    var chart = $(this).parent('div').attr('id');
    chart = chart.replace('_', '');
    $('#' + chart).highcharts().series[0].update({
        type: "bar"
    });
});
$('#set_pie').click(function () {
    var chart = $(this).parent('div').attr('id');
    chart = chart.replace('_', '');
    $('#' + chart).highcharts().series[0].update({
        type: "pie"
    });
});
```

Highcharts creation :

```js
$('#top10').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        margin: [50, 50, 100, 80]
    },
    title: {
        text: 'TOP10'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ' '
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            align: 'right',
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Ilość'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' + 'Ilość: ' + this.y;
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Ilość zgłoszeń, TOP10',
        data: [1, 2, 3, 43],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            rotation: -90,
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            x: 4,
            y: 10,
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Here is a fiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/supergg/zqvNq/4/

Thanks,

Answer (score 12):

You can use inverted parameter in chart and update yAxis. http://jsfiddle.net/n9xkR/8/

```
$('#bar').click(function () {


    chart.inverted = true;
    chart.xAxis[0].update({}, false);
    chart.yAxis[0].update({}, false);
    chart.series[0].update({
        type: 'column'
    });

});
```

Comment: Ok I see that it's working. But it's a bypass not really a bar chart.

Comment: So if it is not perfect, you can destroy and create new chart.

Comment: I can't believe that there is no methode to juste switch the chart type at the level of the chart and not of the series. Thks for your timer Sebastian

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
$.each(chart.series, function (key, series) {
    series.update(
        {type: 'bar'},
        false
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what works for me:

```
function changeType() {
  var series  = chart.series[0];
  var newType = your_condition_here ? 'column' : 'bar';
  var dataArray = [],
      points = series.data;

  series.chart.addSeries({
      type: newType,
      name: series.name,
      color: series.color,
      data: series.options.data
  }, false);
  series.remove();
}
```

It creates new series using the new type and removes the old one.

Free to add more options as you need.

Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

You are able to update the chart type at the level of the chart. Since you have set the type inside the chart attribute, you need to update the same attribute.

```
// Initializing Chart
let probChart = new Highcharts.Chart('container', {
  chart: { 
    type: "line"
  },
});

// Updating Chart Type
probChart.update({
  chart: { type: "column" }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Not sure you find an answer yet or not but I found one link which is 101% useful to you even for future reference. So can you have a look please. I was searching for something else and I found this link and also got your question.

```
   [http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-update/][1]
```

Let me know or accept my answer if this will help to you in any manner. Cheers:)